# Java File object explanation

Tags: java, file

I am trying to understand why File obj is returning as true in the below.

My file "abc.def.txt" is located at C: in Windows 10

```
File file = new File("\\abc.def.txt");
System.out.println(file != null && file.exists()); // Returns true
File file1 = new File("C:\\abc.def.txt");
System.out.println(file1 != null && file1.exists()); //Returns true
```

My file1 should be return as true , since there exists a file by the name "abc.def.txt" at the location.

But I am confused why file object is return as true , and not false since in Windows , there will no location like \abc.def.txt

Can some one please help understand.

Thanks!

Comment: @Gendarme: `file` and `file1` are variables of type `File`.

Comment: In Windows, starting a path with a backslash represents the root directory on the disk. So the 2 paths you have are the same (assuming you are running the program from the C drive).

Comment: What Johnny said.  On Windows, `"C:\\abc.def.txt"` = `"\\abc.def.txt"` if your default drive is already `"C:"`, which is the case 90% of the time.

Comment: BTW same is true for `"/abc.def.txt"` and you can use `getAbsolutePath()` to get the absolute path of a `File` instance

Answer (score 1):

First, let's breakdown what your code is doing:

1. Create an object called `file` at `\\abc.def.txt`
2. Print out `true` If the `file` object isn't `null` **and** `file.exists()` returns `true`
3. Create an object called `file1` at `\\abc.def.txt`
4. Print out `true` If the `file1` object isn't `null` **and** `file.exists()` returns `true`

In response to your question edit, in Windows, beginning with a `\` assumes you are going to the "root" level directory. In your example, that should be `C:` unless specific otherwise.

You are creating both files, and your True / False check is really seeing if they exist, not *where* they exist. If you want to check where they exist you could do something like this:

```
File file = new File("\\abc.def.txt");
boolean check = new File(directory, file).exists();
System.out.println(check); // Returns true
File file1 = new File("C:\\abc.def.txt");
boolean check1 = new File("C:\\", "abc.def.txt").exists();
System.out.println(check1); //Returns true
```

Comment: This is doing the same as OP, there's no difference on using File(directory, file) vs File(fullPath)

Comment: Correct, it should, but this answer also provides much more detail that OP likely needs, and the addition of boolean 'check' variables might help make things clearer for OP.